# Where is ExceptionAggregator.cs

Tags: c#, .net

When I debug my unit tests (I use xUnit) and there occur exception. I get screen (below) with question about location ExceptionAggregator.cs. Where can I found it?

[image]

Comment: see this [issue](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/305)

Comment: It [is here](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core/Sdk/ExceptionAggregator.cs).  Why it didn't make it onto your build machine takes a seance with a psychic.

Comment: I am also getting this error even today in 2019 in debug mode. Seems there is a scenario in which path/symbol of assembly is not loaded. It happens only when tests are failing & not able to find scenarios for Acceptance test feature in implementation

Answer (score 0):

Are you debugging under "Release" build?

I find Visual Studio will step into xUnit Runner thread when debugging under "Release" build.

Build with "Debug" mode, and debug should be fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO ,please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it'll be helping you to put your content quality up .